# XPath validate if element not present or does not contain required value

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to report issues where a certain element is missing or if present does not contain the required value.

My initial when it is present but does not contain the required text is working fine :

```
xmllint ./myfiles*/*.xml --xpath "//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'personName' and not(text() = 'novice')]"
```

How do I also include the case when the tag is missing whole?

here is my attempt which is not working :

```
xmllint ./myfiles*/*.xml --xpath "not(//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'personName' and not(text() = 'personName')]) or (//descendant-or-self::node()[local-name(.) = 'personName' and not(text() = 'novice')])"
```

High level XML

```
<com.mycompany.MyTestClass>
    <id>12312312</id>
    <uberclass>
        .. more xml here
    </uberclass>
    <personAge>11</personAge>
    .. more xml here
    <personName>novice</personName>
    ...more xml here
</com.mycompany.MyTestClass>
```

Comment: Please show a sample of your XML. You talk about attributes, but your XPath code is looking for elements. Either your prose or your code is wrong, but we can't tell which.

Comment: Added in description. Let me know if it does not make sense still.

Comment: I've edited the question to use the correct terminology, so people don't get confused.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `not(X='value')` returns true if the set of nodes selected by X does not include a node whose string value is equal to `value`. This includes the case where the set of nodes selected by X is empty, that is, where the node is absent.

Now the question is, what do you want your expression to return? If you want it to return the relevant element if it exists and has the required value, or an empty node-set otherwise, then you can simply write

```
//personName[. = 'novice']
```

If you want to return a boolean that tells you whether such a node exists, you can write

```
boolean(//personName[. = 'novice'])
```

In fact you can shorten this to

```
//personName = 'novice'
```

though I personally find this less clear, and it has the disadvantage that you can't apply the same contraction to more complex predicates like

```
//personName[starts-with(., 'novice')]
```

If you want the inverse (return true if the element does not exist or does not have the right value), then

```
not(//personName[. = 'novice'])
```